# Slack API Events are not registering in our application

Tags: python, slack, slack-api, bolt

Hello Fellow Slack Bot Enthusiasts.

It's my first time to start setting up a Slack Bot (and I don't have a lot of dev experience, so I wanted to inquire!) .
For this, I used python and Slack bolt.

### Background

I was trying to setup my Amazon EC2 Web Instance's Load Balancer to accept slack events from my Workspace. In the below photo, I am now able to have my Endpoint URL Verified in the Slack bot.

[image: The URL I used is now Verified.]

Next, I am trying to follow the instructions listed in the [Slack Bolt](https://api.slack.com/start/building/bolt-python) homepage that told me to create the app.py test file. So I followed through on the instructions and ensured that I subscribed to below events:

- app_home_opened
- message.channels
- message.groups
- message.im

Then I created the sample app.py file from the article, that was supposed to handle the app_home_opened event.

Now I tried to run the application in my command line (I added the section for @app.event(app_home_opened), and all the other required events ), and I tried to trigger the app_home_opened, message.channels, message.im events, by opening the home page of my bot and by dm-ing the bot and inviting it to a channel and trying to talk to it - but I don't seem to be receiving any payload in the back-end.

[image: Running the test bolt app]

*I wanted to inquire about the "Verified" notification from the Slack Bot. Does this ensure that the connection between my chatbot code and the server are actually linked?*

*In addition, I wanted to inquire about ways to test this so that I can ensure that the connection is actually working as expected.
If you could share some thoughts about what I can do to test the communication, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!*

### Summary

**TLDR:**

***Problem:*** My chatbot is not receiving any payload from Slack.
***Expected:*** I think there should be some interaction saying HTTP / 200 response to indicate that it is OK, etc.
***Actual:*** The chatbot just remains the same saying "⚡Bolt App is Running"

***What I've tried:***

- Reinstalling the application to ensure that all my changes were saved and were reflected properly in my Slack Environment
- Testing the communication by curling through to the URL (it responded with challenge parameter), so I thought that it was OK
- Testing the communication by entering some text via DM / channel communication, and opening the homepage.

***Sample Code:***

```
import os
# Use the package we installed
from slack_bolt import App

# Initializes your app with your bot token and signing secret
app = App(
    token=os.environ.get("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"),
    signing_secret=os.environ.get("SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET")
)

# Add functionality here
# @app.event("app_home_opened") ...
# added some of the code from the guide here and the other @app.events ("")


# Start your app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.start(port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 3000)))
```

Comment: My guess is that slack never reaches your app... Are you behind a proxy (e.g. nginx)? Are you sure the proxy forwards everything properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slack_bolt, for some reason that escapes me, does not seem to create the event handler endpoint (/slack/events) and instead seems to prefer running the application in socket mode. It may still be worth looking into socket mode (see SocketModeHandler) but this example from slack_bolt's github repo ended up getting me to my solution: https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-python/blob/main/examples/flask/app.py

The short-ish version is you have to utilize slack_bolts's flask adapter to create a SlackRequestHandler then create a flask app, define the slack events endpoint (/slack/events) for the flask app, and pass the result to the bolt SlackRequestHandler (Events Endpoint -> Flask -> SlackRequestHandler -> Bolt):

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request

from slack_bolt import App
from slack_bolt.adapter.flask import SlackRequestHandler

bolt_app = App(
    token=os.environ.get("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"),
    signing_secret=os.environ.get("SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET")
)
flask_app = Flask(__name__)
handler = SlackRequestHandler(bolt_app)

# Add functionality here
# @bolt_app.event("app_home_opened") ...
# added some of the code from the guide here and the other @bolt_app.events ("")

@flask_app.route("/slack/events", methods=["POST"])
def slack_events():
    return handler.handle(request)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    flask_app.run()
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Thank you! This ended up being the solution. Apologies for getting back late but we did resolve it through using Flask.